# Classification model with multiple thresholds

Tags: machine-learning, classification, threshold

A model usually has one threshold, for example 0.5, if anything is greater than 0.5 we predict it as 1 vice versa.

However, there are some features that impacts the output probability. Let's say feature `a` can equal to either `0` or `1`. If we split the output results between `0` and `1`, the thresholds gathered for `0` greatly differs from `1`, meaning that the thresholds can be much greater than the probabilities that occurs in `0`. Hence that anything predicted with `0` is automatically equal to `0` class, but in reality that is not true.

Is it logical to create two separate thresholds for the `0` and `1` input variable or maybe just create two individual models instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use model(s) that output class *probabilities*. Whether you should use an omnibus model or separate models should be guided by which approach yields better probabilistic predictions. Use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) to assess this.

Use as many thresholds as required when you use your predictions to make *decisions*. Note that even if there are only two classes (sick/healthy), there may be more than two decisions (treat as sick/run more tests/treat as healthy).

[More here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352)